# Clear cart if different restaurant is selected

Tags: php, cart

I am using cart to store the values in session that user has decided to buy.
Now i want to handle cart in below ways:

The url of page having item details is `http://example.com?id=10`

1. Once items are added in cart then let us say that user changes the restaurant and lands again on page where he can add items again.

   a. If restaurant selected by user is different than earlier then all items should be removed as those were of previously selected restautrant.

   b. If restaurant is same then keep the items as it is.

I am checking the restaurant by the Id passed in URL.

I tried storing `Id` in session on page but how can i verify on same page if restaurant is same or not. Below is the code i tried

```
$_SESSION['res_in_se'] = $_GET['id'] ;
 if($_SESSION['res_in_se'] != $_GET['id']){
     $cart->empty_cart();
 }
```

Comment: You should check that the id is as expected, e.g. integer, between a min and max value etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result by , first checking if session is empty, say user first time selecting the restaurant, set the session value to id of restaurant. Next time you need to reset the session value only if restaurant selected by user is different then previous one. 
You code would be:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['res_in_se']) && isset($_GET['id'])) {
$_SESSION['res_in_se'] = $_GET['id'] ;
}
else
 if($_SESSION['res_in_se'] != $_GET['id']){
     $cart->empty_cart();
     $_SESSION['res_in_se'] = $_GET['id'] ;
 }
```